# Woocommerce show product combination without selecting all combinations

Tags: wordpress, variables, woocommerce, product

I'm developing an e-commerce using Wordpress and I'm having a problem with product variations. I have about 40 photographic works
and each of them has different options:

- print support
- frame color
- dimension

Currently only if a user selects all the choices the image is updated and a price is displayed based on the choices.

I would like a user to see the updated image and price even by selecting one or two of the options.

Is it possible to create a product variation by setting only one or two variations?

Here is a sample product that I would like to change already from the first or second choice of the user. (at the moment the image and the price are updated only by setting all three variations).

product link -> https://www.italiansummer.it/product/addaura/

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the gravatar form plugin.